# apache 2.4.6 proxy https to http Tomcat 7.0.68

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, proxy

I have a Tomcat application running at context "/mycontext". Apache 2.4.6 is handling the front end via a proxy in httpd.conf. I am unable to render pages at /mycontext using https with CA signed certificate.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass         /mycontext  http://example.com:8081/mycontext
  ProxyPassReverse  /mycontext  http://example.com:8081/mycontext
</VirtualHost>
```

Requests sent as http://example.com/mycontext are rendered as expected.

For certain pages at /mycontext we want to use SSL to connect. Example: https://example.com/mycontext/transaction.xhtml using a CA signed certificate.

For https:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certs/ca.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key/private/mykey.key
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  ProxyPass /mycontext http://example.com:8081/mycontext
  ProxyPassReverse /mycontext http://example.com:8081/mycontext
</VirtualHost>
```

My Tomcat connector in server.xml:

```
 <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        proxyName="www.example.com"
        proxyPort="80"
        redirectPort="8443"
        xpoweredBy="false"
        server="Apache TomEE" />
```

*Edit - Since I couldn't get the proxy to redirect to the Connector at port 8081, I defined a second Connector using port 8082 with the proxyPort=443 in Tomcat's server.xml. Still no success.

```
    <Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    proxyName="www.example.com"
    proxyPort="443"
    redirectPort="8443"
    xpoweredBy="false"
    server="Apache TomEE" />
```

Requests to https://example.com/mycontext result in Apache responding:

Not Found

The requested URL /mycontext/ was not found on this server.

Is this a missing or incorrectly set virtual host directive problem? The SSL cert is correctly installed showing the lock icon the "Verified by ....".

Answer (score 0):

The SSL virtualhost is not proxying correctly, and you must match slashes or the lack of them. So you must use:

```
ProxyPass /mycontext http://example.com:8081/mycontext
```

This is what you are using in the non-SSL virtualhost, not sure why you changed it in the SSL virtualhost since as you describe you want to do the same thing.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you. That was a copy/paste error as I'm proxying several context paths.  I've edited to reflect the running directives as well as eliminated the multiple paths in the running code. Still the same result.

Comment: @TedSpradley You mean you are using the same directives in both virtualhost and in SSL it does not work? Or what happens instead?

Comment: Both virtualhost containers above with the respective different directives are what I'm using. Apache response to http://example.com/mycontext renders as expected. Apache response to https://example.com/mycontext renders "The requested URL /mycontext/ was not found on this server.".

Comment: I just experimented with removing the three SSL directives from virtualhost *:443. I still get exactly the same response of "not found".

Comment: Which makes no sense, since httpd won't behave differently in different virtualhost for the same set of directives. Do you have more SSL virtualhosts? Use `apachectl -S` and make sure other SSL virtualhosts have different Servername. Add specific customlog and errorlog directives in this and try to go further reading the logs for this virtualhost, if both come up empty you are landing somewhere else.

Comment: The ssl virtualhost above is the only ssl virtualhost. There is one other non-ssl virtualhost.  apachectl -S verifies the one *:443 virtualhost and the two *:80 virtualhosts. The two port 80 virtualhosts do have different Servername. I created a custom error log for the *:443 virtual host, restarted apache, then tried https://example.com/mydirective, then opened the custom log and custom error log. Both were empty. ssl_access_log contains the line "xx.xxx.xx.xx - - [05/Oct/2016:17:40:46 -0500] "GET /mycontext/ HTTP/1.1" 404 201" - (x's are my ip address obscured)